# Fetching an ID on onclick of a button

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create button dynamically inside a loop. onclick of button i want to fetch the id of the button. The below code is not working. Can anyone please help me.

```
 for(int i=1;i<5;i++)
    {
    var btn = document.createElement("button");
    btn.innerText = "button"+i;
    btn.setAttribute("id", i);
    btn.onclick = function(this){
    alert(this.id);
    }
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to add the button to the document.

Comment: `for(int i=1;i<5;i++)` is it valid Javascript code? I mean `int`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you had to append child . and you cannot use int here . use `var`

```js
for(var i=1;i<5;i++)
    {
    var btn = document.createElement("button");
    
    btn.innerText = ("button"+i);
    btn.setAttribute("id", i);
      document.body.appendChild(btn); // add this line 
    btn.onclick = function(){
    alert(this.id);
    }
  }
```

Comment: and you cannot pass this in function

Comment: @ Mahi can you explain me , why we cannot pass 'this' in function?

Comment: @sanvi4 you shouldn't accept the above answer otherwise it will be problem in understanding who has same problem . since above solution won't work because `this` in function arguments is like variable. and `this` cannot becomes variable . it's like `var this; ` so you cannot do this

Comment: sorry i did not check that..Thank you:)

Answer (score 1):

You first need to add the created element to the document so that it will be added to the DOM. Read this [tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild).

```
for(var i=1;i<5;i++)
{
   var btn = document.createElement("button");
   btn.innerText = "button"+i;
   btn.setAttribute("id", i);
   document.body.appendChild(btn);
   btn.onclick = function(){
     alert(this.id);

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're running into two problems:

1. You for-loop is using `int` to declare the loop variable `i`. In javascript you don't have strong typing, you just need to use `for (var i = 0; ...) {...}`
2. The button element you created exists in code, button hasn't been added to document itself. In general, new elements need to be appended to a parent element that already exists on the page (such as the `body` element where most of the content is).

Checkout the JS Bin below with a working example. In this example I have specified an element with the id "btn-container" as the parent element.

[JS Bin with working example.](https://jsbin.com/vubucaxapi/edit?js,output)

Comment: Thank you Sebastian sangervasi

Comment: No problemo. Is it possible to mark this as answered, or does the "put on hold" prevent that?

Answer (score -1):

```
for(var i = 1; i < 5; i++)
{
    var btn = document.createElement("button");
    btn.innerText = "button"+i;
    btn.setAttribute("id", i);
    btn.onclick = function(e) {
        alert(this.id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Some explanation is in order here. This code sample is almost identical to the code sample in the question and it's not clear how this solution fixes the issue.